# How to crop a user scaled UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I've a `UIImageView *userImage` and `UIImageView *imageSquare` whose size is 320x320. The user will be able to play with `userImage` being able to change size & change position. `imageSquare` is static and placed in the middle of the screen and should be seen as the cropping view

The code below can crop userImage as the `imageSquare` original size but not with its new aspect ratio / scale.

I've been going crazy trying to do this but i cant find a way. How could I crop the current view (*the one the user is manipulating*) of `userImage`?

```
 CGSize pageSize = imageSquare.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageSize);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(resizedContext, -imageSquare.frame.origin.x, -imageSquare.frame.origin.y);


    [userImage.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (image != nil) {
        NSLog(@"is not nil");
        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        imageSquare.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imgData];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 320x320 cropping view should be a UIView with clipsToBounds ("Clip Subviews" in Interface Builder) set to YES, and then userImage should be one of its subviews.

When the user changes size/position, you change userImage.frame, and the cropping will be handled for you.